# How to write test case for below method in controller

Tags: tdd, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit, xunit2

Need code to write xunit test case for ControllerApi

I tried to inject Contructor from xunit test method, but it asking contructor value which I don't have in test method.

Controller
ItemApiController.cs

```
  public class ItemApiController : ControllerBase
  {
         Private ItemClassDataSerices   __ItemClassDataSerices;
         public ItemApiController(IItemClassDataSerices  ItemClassDataSerices)
         {
              __ItemClassDataSerices = ItemClassDataSerices;
         } 

         public ActionResult ItemClass([FromQuery] ItemRequest request)
         {
               return __ItemClassDataSerices.GetData(reqest);            
         }
  }
```

Now how  to write Xunit test method for ItemClass method which is present in ItemApiController.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of tests are named Integration tests. You can follow the Microsoft documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2

The documentation has a lot of examples, and some code about startup configuration to use your DI inside your tests